# How to set the default view into last page in pagination:PHP

Tags: php, pagination

Here is my script which I got from the internet,

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// number of results to show per page
$per_page = 5;

// figure out the total pages in the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY id"))
{
if ($result->num_rows != 0)
{
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
// ceil() returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

// check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
$show_page = $_GET['page'];

// make sure the $show_page value is valid
if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
{
$start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
$end = $start + $per_page;
}
else
{
// error - show first set of results
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}
}
else
{
// if page isn't set, show first set of results
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}

// display pagination
echo "<p><a href='view.php'>View All</a> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i)
{
echo $i . " ";
}
else
{
echo "<a href='view-paginated.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
}
}
echo "</p>";

// display data in table
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
// make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

// find specific row
$result->data_seek($i);
$row = $result->fetch_row();

// echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row[1] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row[2] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="records.php?id=' . $row[0] . '">Edit</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row[0] . '">Delete</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";
}

// close table>
echo "</table>";
}
else
{
echo "No results to display!";
}
}
// error with the query
else
{
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

// close database connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

This program views the 1st page but I want to set the default view into last page after inserted the last row data into the table "players".  I got one something like reverse pagination but I don't know how to set it. I'm not good at php. please help!

Comment: Reverse the order of the results?

Comment: Yes. I want to view the last 5 rows after submit  the last id into the table.

Comment: `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY id DESC")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried this one but it is not the one I need. sorry. If I use DESC, the view.php shows the URL as http://localhost/records/view.php?page=1   but what I actually need to do is, if the last inserted id was 20, I want to get the default view as http://localhost/records/view.php?page=20. But thanks for the help anyway